# OpenGL + Object-Orientation?

Tags: opengl, c++11

I recently decided to add some RAII to the OpenGL objects, until I realized that it was futile and contradicted how OpenGL was setup- as a state system. Now, I actually want to implement a class for a game involving OpenGL objects, like so:

```
class RenderTarget: public boost::noncopyable{
public:
    virtual ~RenderTarget();

protected:
    clear(const ColorSet& color);
    copy_to(const RenderTarget& target) = 0;
    copy_from(const RenderTarget& target) = 0;
    attach(const RenderTarget& target);
    detach(const RenderTarget& target);

private:
    //set of opengl framebuffers/renderbuffers/etc. ?
};
```

As you can see I would like this abstract to contain a set of opengl framebuffers, however the problem is that since opengl is a state machine, whenever I want to call any of the member functions i would either have to:
assume that the member framebuffer is bound (bad), call bind/unbind every time the function is called (expensive), or expose a bind()/unbind() interface (ugly, exposes OpenGL semantics). I'm kind of stuck here. Am I thinking about this the wrong way?

Comment: Probably interessting for you: [oglplus](http://oglplus.org/) is a object-oriented facade for OpenGL - featuring C++11 features also

Comment: @Constantin i checked into it, but decided against it. gl doesn't really lend itself to oo.

Comment: If you can live with your software only running on NV / AMD hardware, you can avoid the selector / latch design of OpenGL (e.g. bind, then modify) by using [`GL_EXT_direct_state_access`](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/direct_state_access.txt). Sadly, Intel, Mesa and Apple still have not implemented that extension; it would make what you are trying to do so much easier if they would.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman interesting, though i am targeting mac.

Comment: You could always add logic to your functions to query the *current* binding before you do any of these things that require you to bind an object, and then restore it at the end. This adds a minor bit of API overhead (for querying anyway... restoring the binding may be much more expensive for some object types) and a tremendous amount of coding overhead.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: what if I stored which object were bound in a global state structure? the problem with that is that a misplaced glBindX() function could cause all sorts of strange bugs, however querying opengl is very expensive...

Comment: @Shokwav: I wrote an "answer" that shows how I implemented the state structure you are proposing. Having binding stacks will probably help you out a lot. When your function that has to bind a certain object to work begins, you can push the current binding and when it finishes you can pop the old one to restore it. If the thing that was already bound was your object then no actual work has to take place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually have a design similar to what you were discussing for a project of mine, only instead of using a global array I have a class that serves as the interface to the state machine and provides some functionality similar to the deprecated state stack.

#### Example binding state:

```
class FrameBufferBindState {
friend class eTB_RenderContext;
protected:
  FrameBufferBindState (void) {
    reset ();
  }

  void reset (void) {
    bound      = NULL;
    swap_count = 0;
    req_count  = 0;
  }

  void bind (eTB_FrameBuffer* fbo);

  void push (void);
  void pop  (void);

  eTB_FrameBuffer* bound;
  int              swap_count;
  int              req_count;

  std::stack <eTB_FrameBuffer *> stack;
};
```

I have a class called `eTB_RenderContext` that contains instances of classes like this for each fundamental class of object the engine can bind (note that some of these classes also contain bindings themselves, for instance program objects have shader objects bound to them).

I keep track of the number of times `bind (...)` was called (`req_count`) versus the number of times the binding actually had to be changed (`swap_count`) to measure batch efficiency. I also have a stack mechanism for bindings and states to make some algorithms easier.

#### Binding classes:

```
  VertexArrayBindState vertex_array_;
  ProgramBindState     program_;
  FrameBufferBindState framebuffer_;
  SamplerBindState*    samplers_;       // Minimum: 80 in GL4
  TextureBindState*    texture_images_; // Minimum: 80 in GL4
```

Comment: I like this, it works well assuming you hide #includes to gl.h so that users cannot manually change state without going through the interface. How do you expose other framebuffer-related functions? Through those objects themselves?

Comment: Yeah, you have to slap someone on the wrist for doing that. But in a portable graphics engine the application should rarely if ever be interfacing directly with a low-level graphics API. Otherwise, porting games between consoles would be a nightmare ;)

Comment: @Shokwav: Regarding setting framebuffer state, the class `eTB_FrameBuffer` manages its own state in a similar way, sort of its own mini state machine. Attachments in `eTB_FrameBuffer` work similarly to bindings in `eTB_RenderContext`, only they are localized to a single FBO.

Answer (score 1):

RAII is still good for resource management in OpenGL (textures need IDs, etc which should be freed if for example you reach the next level in the game and load new assets).  These tasks are done infrequently and object-oriented overhead has minimal effect on responsiveness.

But for individual rendering and mid-frame state management, encapsulation creates a lot of inefficiency (e.g. uploading color and texture binding for each object) while good OpenGL performance requires minimizing state changes.  Even detection and elision of redundant state changes doesn't help much, you need to submit geometry in sorted order, not grouped according to some abstract object model.

Comment: The problem is that RAII becomes more complex when you factor in that any calls to the gl require a context, so you need to check for one both in the constructor and the destructor.

Comment: @Shokwav: Only if your program uses multiple contexts.  I never make my RAII objects aware of the context, except for the single class in charge of cleaning up the context later.

Comment: Agree this this.  I use RAII for allocation and release of resources, but have a state object that maintains bind state.  Note that if you store bind state in a state object that you submit to your renderer, the renderer might well be able to use it for sorting in some manner too.